# Flutter: How to convert a stateful widget to a stateless widget and keep state changes

Tags: flutter, dart, statelesswidget

I want to change a stateful widget to a stateless widget and keep the set states functions available, how can I do it?

Comment: The question sounds like you want to eat the cake and keep it at the same time. Could you clarify your intent?

Comment: there's no way we can change a class type at runtime. Clarify what do you wanna do but the answer is probably simple: if your widget has a state then it's a stateful widget not a stateless, this also sounds like a XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do it by cubit with the stateless widgets,like this:
https://medium.com/@kidherbert43/flutter-study-cubit-with-stateless-widget-2f4cd941edec

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have `setState` on Stateless widget.
`setState` method comes from [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html).

You can use [ValueListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) or you can pass new data through constructor and call setState on parent both UI will get refresh. Also you can use state management property like provider/riverpod/bloc to manage the state.

More about [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) and [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html).

Comment: can't use StatefulBuilder in Stateless widget?

Comment: StatefulBuilder comes with state class, yes it can be used but what makes different using StateFullWidget? Rebuild the full widget tree. Then  StateFullWidget is better than this. where can have fine control using ValueListenableBuilder

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StatefulBuilder` like this:

```
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color color = Colors.red;
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, innerstate) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                innerstate(() {
                  color = Colors.black;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                color: color,
              ),
            );
          }),
        )
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't just post random, uncomplete code. What does `customTheme()`, `CheckBox`, deletedNote etc have to do with OPs question?

Comment: @RobertSandberg It was not random code just show the use case of StatefulBuilder, but in order to clear the answer,I provided some better answer.

Comment: Yeah I understand the StatefulBuilder, but when adding a lot of junk it ruins the clarity of the answer. Those extra things have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change states in a stateless widget rather than information is inherited. Stateless is not expecting any changes like stateful in runtime. But stateless can change their interface in runtime due to information given before at widget build.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with Bloc, Provider, Riverpod and many other State Management solutions.